# Loop devexpress controls WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to loop through all of the controls in a Windows Form, and get their names.

I did this easily with recursion, but since the Form includes DevExpress controls a problem occurs.

An example is a control of the type RibbonControl (DevExpress control) - the problem is that this control does NOT have children. I inspected the RibbonControl, and saw that it has a property called "Items" which includes the children for this DevExpress control.

So my question is, is there a way to loop through the children of DevExpress controls like this one?
I tried with Control.Items, but this does not work unless the control is casted to a RibbonControl, and this is not a good approach, since there are more types (which i still don't know) that have "items" instead of "children".

```
foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(RibbonControl))
    {
        var ribbonCnt = (RibbonControl) control;
        foreach (var cnt in ribbonCnt.Items)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way i currently get the children (items) of the RibbonControl, but since this control may vary - this doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: What are you trying to do? (OK, Loop through all controls, obviously. But what _problem_ are you trying to solve by doing that?)

Comment: The endpoint is to create an XML with all the labels in the form. The current one i get has the RibbonControl in it, but not it's children which are of BarButton type. Another example for this is the NavBarControl, which has NavBarGroups/Items as children, but are also stored in items. Since getting the type of the control in runtime and casting is impossible, i'm stuck.

Comment: BTW, if the set of controls that have .items instead of .controls is finite, that can be an approach too.

Comment: By "labels" you mean `Control.Name` ?

Comment: I pull multiple information, Control.GetType(), Contorl.Name, Control.Text...
The DevExpress sub - items (which i'm trying to loop) have Captions instead of those, so I guess i'll need these in that case

Comment: Maybe it's worthwhile to look into DevExpress and find if all their Controls have a common root that has the properties you need. So you only need to check for that type.

Comment: Not all devexpress controls will make it into the controls collection. So the way you are doing it now is the only way to do this. I asked the same question to their support site about menuitems in there BarManager and I got the same answer

Comment: So there is no way to get the BarItems? I mean i know you can access them with .items, but only if you are sure the control is a BarManager. But what if you just have a control?

Comment: You could iterate through them and check objControl.GetType.GetProperty("Items") to determine if you iterate them as Collection or Items